# Symfony2 Database separation

Tags: php, symfony, model, controller

I was trying to setup a UserModel Class and very unhappy with the separation of database and Models.

For example I want to check if Username already exists or generate a new User. But all these actions require a database connection, which is only available in a controller. Of course i can always inject the DB Object, but it just feels wrong. What is the right way to handle these things?

Comment: "I want to check if Username already exists or generate a new User. But all these actions require a database connection, which is only available in a controller" 
And where do you want to perform this action? Don't say that in model itself.

Comment: No, in a seperated class which should handle my "user" logic.

Comment: Then you should configure a service for your class, pass doctrine EM or repository, retrieve it from container in controller (not manual instantiation ) and call method which should encapsulate all the logic. Read more about service container http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UniqueEntity validator, the docs are here

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

About the db connection, you can easily inject specific repositories  or the entity manager itself in your services where needed.